# The when others then does not work. However, the first exception handling works if the department name does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have tried to solve this problem by adding when others then but it does not seem to work. It only works when the department name does not exist, it would show No DATA FOUND but when the department name matches, it does not show anything. I want to know how I can fix this issue

```
DECLARE
   dept_id      departments.department_id%TYPE;
   mgr_id       departments.manager_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT   department_ID, Manager_ID 
        INTO   dept_id, mgr_id
        FROM   departments
    Where  Department_name = 'IT'; 
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The department ID is: ' || dept_id || 
                 '; Manager ID is: ' || mgr_id);  
                     -- change the value of IT to 'ABC'

END;
```

I have to use when others for this problem

Comment: OTHERS is for *other* exceptions.  If your select works, then there is no exception.I would recommend reading the oracle pl/sql documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will be selected and will be available to use just after the select statement.When the select statement fails the control jumps to exception block. User can handle exception as desired. Purpose of when others is to handle any Exception that has not been handled, primary used when developer doesn't have any control and wan't to handle ANY exception. For example TOO_MANY_ROWS is not handled in the code but will get caught in the OTHERS Exception.

```
 DECLARE
       dept_id      departments.department_id%TYPE;
       mgr_id       departments.manager_id%TYPE;
    BEGIN

       SELECT   department_ID, Manager_ID 
            INTO   dept_id, mgr_id
            FROM   departments
        Where  Department_name = 'IT'; 

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('The department ID is: ' || dept_id || 
                     '; Manager ID is: ' || mgr_id);

     IF dept_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
         UPDATE departments
         SET DEPARTMENT_NAME ='ABC'
         WHERE department_ID = dept_id
         AND Manager_ID = mgr_id;
     END IF;

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA FOUND');

        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' In other Error '||SQLERRM||' '||SQLCODE);  
                         -- change the value of IT to 'ABC'

    END;
```